# EC2 ubuntu machine not able to connect to PostgreSQL RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have an EC2 Ubuntu machine that is trying to establish a connection to Postgress RDS Machine.
I have allowed all outbound traffic for my ec2 machine.
for inbound for RDS, I have allowed all UDP, all TCP, and all ICMP Ipv4 traffic with source as a security group of EC2 machine.

I feel my EC2 is not able to connect to the RDS instance.
Both are in the same default VPC.

I tried :

```
ping hostname
```

from my EC2, which doesn't connect and also tried

```
 psql yellow-pages -U yp_develop -h hostname Password
```

I get

```
psql: FATAL:  database "yellow-pages" does not exist
```

anything that I am missing or I understood the concept wrongly that I am not able to solve this issue.

Please if anyone cloud solve this problem.

Comment: Ping won't work to RDS, but does it at least resolve the hostname? Does it resolve it to a public ip or a private ip? Does running `telnet hostname 5432` connect to your DB?

Comment: hey, @ChrisWilliams hope you're doing well.
I tried running telnet it gave the below output 
Trying 172.31.21.223...
Connected to ec2-15-185-178-141.me-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com.
Escape character is '^]'.

Comment: OK great so that actually connected to the RDS instance, right can you confirm running `psql -U yp_develop -h hostname -l Password`? This should list all databases that exist

Comment: @ChrisWilliams getting a weird error when I try the this command 
"psql: FATAL:  database "password" does not exist"

Comment: Remove the word Password too

Comment: @ChrisWilliams I can see the databases list.
how can use the database and check it my table which I am able to see in PGAdmin is there or not

Comment: Use the command `psql -U yp_develop -h hostname $DBNAME` where $DBNAME is the database name you want to use

Comment: I am into the database used 

YELLOWPAGES-> \dt
             List of relations
 Schema |     Name     | Type  |   Owner
--------+--------------+-------+------------
 public | YP_SUPPLIERS | table | yp_develop
(1 row)

But when I run SELECT * from YP_SUPPLIERS;
I am getting 
ERROR:  relation "yp_suppliers" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * from YP_SUPPLIERS;

Comment: Great, I have added the steps we took as the answer below :)

Comment: Ya thanks to you.
You are a lifesaver.

but I am not able to select the table don't view the content

Comment: Once you run the PSQL command you should be able to run any native SQL syntax such as `SELECT * FROM YP_SUPPLIERS;` Make sure to add the ';'

Comment: I am within the database Yellowpages.
ran \d which listed me the schema present 
             List of relations
 Schema |     Name     | Type  |   Owner
--------+--------------+-------+------------
 public | YP_SUPPLIERS | table | yp_develop

now I ran 
YELLOWPAGES-> SELECT * from YP_SUPPLIERS;

which throws an error ERROR: relation "yp_suppliers" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT * from YP_SUPPLIERS;

Comment: Hmm how about `SELECT * FROM public."YP_SUPPLIERS"`?

Comment: got it I was running wrong syntax, forgot to put YP_SUPPLIERS within  " ".  :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database is connectable by attempting to use telnet to connect to it.

The issue appeared to be that either the user does not have permission to the database `yellow-pages` or the database `yellow-pages` does not exist.

To validate this the `telnet $HOSTNAME 5432` command was run and it was able to connect.

After this the `psql -U yp_develop -h $HOSTNAME -l` command was carried out validating that there was no `yellow-pages` database setup on this RDS instance.

Comment: I also have a question, how does RDS interact with EC2.
Hostname or private IP or Public IP or Elastic IP.

Comment: How do you mean so? Could you expand so I can ensure I understand the question? :)

Comment: The EC2 machine is an API server that interacts with RDS to fetch the info.
currently, the developer has configured http://private ip:5000. in connection somewhere.

when I used  curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:5000/api/Supplier' 
I am able to featch the info .

But when I use 
 curl --location --request GET 'http://privateip:5000/api/Supplier' 

it gives me curl: (7) Failed to connect to private ip port 5000: Connection refused.

Comment: That would be an issue with either the web server itself (not exposing itself) or security group issue. Probably worth raising a secondary question for that :)

Comment: :D hope i find you again